# Using Jboss Fuse, Is there a way to persist a flat file into a DB?

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse, teiid

I have to persist flat file data into a MySql Db, I've tried Teiid but it just let me create the virtual DB; I want to import the file and persist it in the same process. Any idea?

Comment: If you read the file contents using Teiid, then use SQL like INSERT INTO mysqldb.foo(x, y) SELECT x, y FROM Teiid.textTable and you have persisted table. If you want to do this at a periodic interval look into materialization techniques.

Comment: Hello Ramesh, thanks for your answer. To perfom my INSERT INTO mysql, all I have to do is create a new Data Source pointing to MySql, or do I also have to add it to my transformation? Thanks again!

Comment: You need add a datasource configuration and source model in the vdb then you csn issue the command